# Get a domain from Socket

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am trying to get the domain a user is connection to (e.g. test.somesite.com) from a Socket, is this possible? The reason I would like this is to redirect users based on where they came from. I get the socket from running serverSocket.accept() in another thread

I have tried:

```
clientSocket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress();
clientSocket.getHostAddress().toString();
```

They both just print my own local/internal IP address. How can I get the domain they came through from that?

Edit: I think this could be possible because for example, in an Apache web server you can do this in your httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName something.something.com
  ProxyPass               /       http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse        /       http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

This will listen on port 80, check if the url they came from is something.something.com, and if it is it will redirect to port 80. Maybe I am completely wrong because I'm new to networking in Java but please let me know if you have any hints, even if I have to rewrite my code its fine.

Edit 2: I found out this is impossible because the target application resolves the domain name to an IP address before it connects. Thanks for all your help though

Keir

Comment: Can you put an example of what would you expect?

Comment: I don't think the Apache ServerName directive is doing what you think it is. It is used to identify the virtual host definition by using the Host header sent by a client. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName()
```

**Update:** Alternatively, try this:

```
((InetSocketAddress)clientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress()).getAddress().getHostName()
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't display the domain they were connected through. Thanks though. I made an edit to my original post to explain more.

Comment: @iKeirNez: It should have worked. `Socket.getInetAddress()` returns an `InetAddress` for the **remote** endpoint of the socket, then `InetAddress.getHostName()` performs a reverse DNS lookup of that IP to get its hostname. You could try using `Socket.getRemoteSocketAddress()` to get the `InetAddress` instead.

Comment: The update didn't work either, I'm trying to get the domain the client is connecting to, not their hostname. Basically if a client uses the ip something.something.com to connect to an IP address, I want to find out the ip they joined through, in this case something.something.com

Edit: I found out its impossible to do as the client that connects to it resolves the domain to an IP before connecting. Thanks for the help though

Comment: You are referring to the domain of the **WEBSERVER**? You can't get that from the socket itself, because the client resolves the hostname before connecting. That is why the HTTP protocol defines a `Host` request header instead. The client must explicitly specify in its HTTP request the Host that it is trying to reach. Virtual Hosts are based on that header, and it is a required header in HTTP 1.1 requests for exactly that reason. In HTTP 1.0, it is an optional header, but then Virtual Hosts do not work. So it is customary for clients to always include a `Host` header in every request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the domain without a DNS, but you could use the [getRemoteSocketAddress()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getRemoteSocketAddress%28%29) method from clientSocket to get the client IP address.

```
clientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for but I edited my original post with more info